# Generating series subtraction

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

If after subtracting two generating series, we get an expression such as:

$1−(1/x^2)$

does this mean that the resulting series has coefficient 0 for all (x, x^2, x^3, x^4,....) or is it not even considered a valid one because the x^2 is in the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider an (ordinary) *[generating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Ordinary_generating_function_(OGF))* $A(x)$ to be an expression of the form
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j\\
&=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots
\end{align*}

The difference $A(x)-B(x)$ of two generating series has the form
\begin{align*}
A(x)-B(x)&=\left(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots\right)-\left(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots\right)\\
&=\left(a_0-b_0\right)+(a_1-b_1)x+(a_2-b_2)x^2+\cdots
\end{align*}
We observe the difference of two (ordinary) generating series is again an ordinary generating series with terms $a_jx^j$, $j$ non-negative integers.

> The expression 
>   \begin{align*}
> 1-\frac{1}{x^2}=1-x^{\color{blue}{-2}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   has $\color{blue}{-2}$ as exponent which is negative. So, this is no generating series at all and can't be the result of a subtraction of two generating series. It seems there was a wrong calculation leading to (1).

Answer (score 1):

$$1-(1/x^2)$$ is not a valid power series because it does not have a well defined constant coefficient (i.e. the coefficient of $x^0$).

Comment: It has a well defined constant term, namely $1$. The problem is the other  term.

Comment: I meant if considered as a power series. The expression has a constant term of 1, but it isn't equal to a power series because that power series wouldn't have a well-defined constant term. Note, the expression $1+\frac{1}{x-1}$ as a power series has a well defined constant term of 2.

Comment: Note that $1+\frac{1}{x-1}=-x-x^2-x^3-x^4-\cdots$ admits a series expansion at $x=0$ which is convergent for $|x|<1$. On the other hand $1-\frac{1}{x^2}$ is a Laurent series with a pole of order two at $x=0$.

Comment: Typo, I meant $1/(1-x)$ not $1/(x-1)$. Anyways, when we talk about generating series, convergence is irrelevant. I think you're thinking like an analyst and not like a combinatorist; to say $1/(1-x)$ is equivalent to a generating series (and therefore a formal power series) is quite standard. To say $1-1/x^2$ is a generating series is incorrect for the reason I started in the original answer.